# Can't use React-Bootstrap with Expo ( Unable to resolve module react/jsx-runtime )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I'm building a react-Native app with Expo, so I tried to use the components from the bootstrap library. I created a new project:

```
expo init test-app
```

then I installed the library in the project folder:

```
expo install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.1.0
```

and I get this output with some unrelated warnings:

> Installing 2 other packages using npm.

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
> notsup SKIPPING
> OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted
> {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> added 24 packages from 48 contributors and audited 1045 packages in
> 9.112s
>
> 29 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 8 vulnerabilities (6 low, 2 moderate)   run `npm audit fix` to
> fix them, or `npm audit` for details

I import the component

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

but when I compile, the following message is shown:
[Screenshot of the expo panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEq1d.png),

> Unable to resolve module react/jsx-runtime from
> C:\Users\Daniele\Documents\Coding\RipassoReact\test-app\node_modules\react-bootstrap\cjs\Button.js:
> react/jsx-runtime could not be found within the project.

I tried so many ways including wiping the node_modules folder and reinstalling them.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem seems to be that you are trying to use Bootstrap which is available for React but not for React Native.

Try to find a different Library that supports your needs like **React Native Elements** (https://reactnativeelements.com/) or use the Elements that you get from React Native directly.

Comment: [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/) is the best (personal choice). [native-base](https://nativebase.io/) is also good.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
npm install react-bootstrap
```

and

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```